# Java Regex Question Mark

Tags: java, regex

When trying to match `"??M?E???"` with pattern `"^([\\?]+)M([\\?]+)E([\\?]+)$"`, I get "No match", although it works for `"?M?E??"` fine.

My code snippet is

```
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([?]+)[M]{1}([?]+)[E]{1}([?]+)$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        if ( !m.find() ) {
            System.out.println("No Match");
            continue ;
        }
        x = m.group(1).length();
        y = m.group(2).length();
        z = m.group(3).length();
```

Comment: I tried the code you posted after your edit and it works fine. Produces `2, 1, 3` for `??M?E???` and `1, 1, 2` for `?M?E??`. You must be doing something else wrong, in code you didn't post, or your input is actually different than what you say it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine, your regex is good. Note that you don't need to escape `?` inside a character class, you can simply:

```
^([?]+)M([?]+)E([?]+)$
```

Or, escape it but get it out the class<sup>*</sup>:

```
^(\?+)M(\?+)E(\?+)$
```

<sup>* Note that in Java, `\` is represented as `\\`</sup>

After you've edited your question and posted the actual code, looks like you have a different regex (please don't do that next time), you should use `matches` instead of `find`. Your problem must be because of the content of `input`, it simply doesn't make `find` return `true`, note that `find` tries to find the next occurrence within the substring that matches the regex.

Answer (score 1):

What does your code look like? This works fine:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([\\?]+)M([\\?]+)E([\\?]+)$");

System.out.println(pattern.matcher("??M?E???").matches());
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("?M?E??").matches());
```

Output:

```
true
true
```